# Meaning of VideoCapture prop definitions not in the opencv documentation

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

Is there any to tell what the meaning of video capture properties that aren't defined in the official documentation?  For example,

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
```

Video properties can be polled with either:
`cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)` or `cap.get(5)`

The opencv [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d) defines all the props up to 51.  But there are metadata properties at index 55, 68, 69 and 70 but they don't have a corresponding definition in the documentation.  Are they defined somewhere else?  Perhaps in an mp4 or h.264 spec?

Comment: the docs you linked to literally say "*See also [Additional flags for video I/O API backends](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dfc/group__videoio__flags__others.html)*" where all the others are documented AND the indices 55, ... that you claim don't have docs **do** have docs *right on the page you linked*

Answer (score 1):

There are more than 200... here a how to list them

```
import cv2


print(f"{'Counter':<8}{'ID':<8}{'Name'}")
i = 0
for attr in dir(cv2):
    if attr.startswith('CAP_PROP'):
        print(f"{i:<8}{getattr(cv2, attr):<8}{attr}")
        i += 1
```

Output

```
Counter ID      Name
0       17008   CAP_PROP_APERTURE
1       600     CAP_PROP_ARAVIS_AUTOTRIGGER
2       63      CAP_PROP_AUDIO_BASE_INDEX
3       61      CAP_PROP_AUDIO_DATA_DEPTH
[...]
24      31      CAP_PROP_DC1394_MAX
25      -2      CAP_PROP_DC1394_MODE_AUTO
26      -3      CAP_PROP_DC1394_MODE_MANUAL
27      -1      CAP_PROP_DC1394_MODE_ONE_PUSH_AUTO
28      -4      CAP_PROP_DC1394_OFF
29      15      CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE
30      17009   CAP_PROP_EXPOSUREPROGRAM
31      28      CAP_PROP_FOCUS
[...]
276     450     CAP_PROP_XI_WB_KB
277     449     CAP_PROP_XI_WB_KG
278     448     CAP_PROP_XI_WB_KR
279     451     CAP_PROP_XI_WIDTH
280     27      CAP_PROP_ZOOM
```

It could be useful to sort them per ID or put them in a dictionary form

```
def cap_prop() -> dict:
    pairs = [(getattr(cv2, attr), attr) for attr in dir(cv2) if attr.startswith('CAP_PROP')]
    pairs.sort()
    return dict(pairs)

props = cap_prop()

print(props.get(10, None))
#CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS
print(props.get(71, None)) # use the get-form, IDs are not complete!
#None
```